# Counter with react useState hook is not working right

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I am new to React. I did a counter with useState hook; the app displays + and - buttons and a text, initially 0.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function App() {

  const [state, setState] = useState({
    count: 0,
    bool: false,
    incValue: 1
  })

  if (state.count >= 10 || state.count <= -10) {
    setState({incValue: 10})
  }

  const incrementCount = () => {
    setState(prevState => {
      return {
        count: prevState.count + state.incValue
      }
    })
  }

  const decrementCount = () => {
    setState(prevState => {
      return {
        count: prevState.count - state.incValue
      }
    })
  }

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={decrementCount}>-</button>
      <span>{state.count}</span>
      <button onClick={incrementCount}>+</button>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

But there is a bug and I couldn't find the reason. When I don't initialize `incValue: 1` state, and increment with 1 instead of `state.incValue`, it works. Why doesn't the code above work?

Comment: The error is fired when you click on the second time ?

Comment: @HamzaKhattabi, yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `{ ...prevState, count: value }` when you try to update the state hook.
And there is another bug with `if` block. When the condition is `true` that block will always inkoved and it lead to `Too many re-renders` error. To fix it use `useEffect` hook. So your code will be:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    count: 0,
    bool: false,
    incValue: 1
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (state.count >= 10 || state.count <= -10) {
      setState({ ...state, incValue: 10 });
    }
  }, [state.count]);

  const incrementCount = () => {
    setState((prevState) => {
      return {
        ...state,
        count: prevState.count + state.incValue
      };
    });
  };

  const decrementCount = () => {
    setState((prevState) => {
      return {
        ...state,
        count: prevState.count - state.incValue
      };
    });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={decrementCount}>-</button>
      <span>{state.count}</span>
      <button onClick={incrementCount}>+</button>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

When you updated the state, you erased the properties `bool` and `inc` values.
Indeed, you created a new object with only the count value.
To keep the entire state and just update one field you have to copy it like that :

For decrement :

```
 setState(prevState => {
      return {
        ...prevState, //Copy the current state and update only the count
        count: prevState.count - state.incValue
      }
```

it is the same for increment:

```
 setState(prevState => {
      return {
        ...prevState, //Copy the current state and update only the count
        count: prevState.count + state.incValue
      }
```